# Request has invalid auth credentials error while GET request to People API

Tags: actions-on-google, gcloud, service-accounts, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, google-people-api

I am making an action-on-google to view to contact details of the signed in user. I have already obtained the access token for my identity provider.
When making a GET request using this access token , I got an error as

> Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the people.googleapis.com. We recommend configuring the billing/quota_project setting in gcloud or using a service account through the auth/impersonate_service_account setting. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/

So I enabled/created a service account which is active . But now when I try to make a GET request to
**[https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?access_token={{token}}](https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?access_token=%7B%7Btoken%7D%7D)**
I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Code :

```
app.intent("sendgc_input",(conv)=>{
    name = `${conv.input.raw}`,
    console.log(name);

    const options = {
        method : 'GET',
        url : 'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?access_token=ya29.a0AfH6SMCXFju5HUe4qHSsKiVJ1tRkzJ3prL7Fe8qqGKHuJCSWYvXaekdEBRTjAZsc1-xbFrlP6W7r7VLtL2KLm3C6UogsX-6peHtv2cPRhvcFV9AB1utoEQcoX2v08eQpx_fNplogeqdzRJyhP6egJTVAfkboEmgUzOQ',
        json : true
    }
    var data=[];
    return rp(options)
            .then(function(parseBody){
                var x = parseBody.email;
                console.log(x)
                data.push(parseBody.email);
                var str = 'A gift card will be sent to' + name + 'on email' + data[0];
                console.log(data);
                return conv.ask(str);
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                console.log(err);
                conv.ask('error');
            })
});
```

I have also done *gcloud auth application-default login* to my accountwith current project.

I don't understand what is going wrong.

Comment: It is difficult to follow exactly what you're describing. Please update your question showing your code and how you're getting the access token. You've indicated you've 'obtained the access token for your identity provider" - can you elaborate on what you mean by this? How is the user authorizing use of the People API? How do you have Account Linking configured in the Actions on Google console? (Masking any private information.) The more you can provide about the entire process - the better our chances are of being able to help.

Comment: It is not enough to just create a service account, you also have to [implement it into your code](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) to use it. The authentication flow with a service account is completely different from noraml user authetication - htere is not passing / using of authentication tokens, but instead you use the Service account credentials obtained from the GCP console. Have a thourough read through the documentation.

Comment: @Prisoner Account linking is done by oauth. The code has been updated

Comment: @ziganotschka is there any other alternative without the use of service account

Comment: I am not 100% sure of what you are trying to do, but to view contacts of a signed in user - the access token must originate from this user - each user needs his own token. The user needs to authorize the app to retrieve his contacts. If th euser gives the authentication once, you can obtain [offline access](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline) so the user won't be prompted for authorizaion each time the access token expires (happens after 60 minutes).